# autoFocus on input when opening modal does not work - React Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-bootstrap

I have a modal that has 3 components. Each component represents a stage, so for example the first component is inputing the user's first name when the user click next, and it will go to the next component, which is inputing address and then user clicks next and it will take the user to the last stage, inputing a nickname. On every `input` element from the components, it will have an `autoFocus`.  So far in the last two components, the `inputs` have an autoFocus except for the first component.

Not sure why the first doesn't have it, when I initialise the modal I see the `input` doesn't have the `autoFocus`, then I hit next then the second component `input` has it and I go back to the first component - hit the back button - then I see the `input` from the first component has an `autoFocus`. Very strange, I've been trying so many way to resolve this, from setting `autoFocus={false}` to the modal, creating a `ref` for the first input but still not working.

It looks like it's an issue with the modal, where it's initialized the focus is somewhere but not on the `input`.  Has anyone encountered this issue?

Example (pseudo) code

```
//Component Hosting the modal

render(){

    if(this.state.modal_stage === 1){
        <FirstName />
    }else if(this.state.modal_stage === 2){
        <LasgtName />

    }else if(this.state.modal_stage === 3){
        <NickName />
    }
    return(

        <Modal 
            dialogClassName="locationModal customModal"
            show={this.state.modalShow} onHide={this.hideModal}
            autoFocus="false">
            <Modal.Header>
                <div className="closeModal" onClick={this.hideModal}></div>
            </Modal.Header>

            <Modal.Body>

                { current_stage}

            </Modal.Body>

            <Modal.Footer>
                {backButton}
                {nextButton}
            </Modal.Footer>

        </Modal>


    );
}


//<FirstName /> component

constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.inputRef = React.createRef();
}

componentDidMount(){
    this.inputRef.current.focus();
}

....

render(){


    return(
        <div>
            <input type="text" placeholder="firstName" ref={this.inputRef}/>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Your help will be appreciated!!

**Note:**

I tried to set this `autoFocus="false"` to `autoFocus={false}` in the modal but the issue still remains.

Comment: It should be `autoFocus={false}` instead of `autoFocus="false"` for your Modal component.

Comment: I tried that already, the issue still persists

Comment: Can you replicate the issue with some workable codes using code sandbox or something ? It will be easier for us to help you with your problem in that way.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Found out a solution that will fix your problem. You can add a little timeout for your component to focus on your input. This should fix your issue.

```
class FirstInput extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.innerRef = React.createRef();
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    // Add a timeout here
    setTimeout(() => {
      this.innerRef.current.focus();
    }, 1)
  }

  render() {
    return <input ref={this.innerRef} />;
  }
}
```

This is a working example: https://codesandbox.io/s/react-bootstrap-autofocus-efkve?fontsize=14

Comment: this works, but more one question why do we need the `setTimeOut`?

Comment: I am guessing there's some transition time going on for Bootstrap modal show animation. Maybe the `input` element hasn't mount yet. So adding just a slight window should solve the problem.

Comment: Oh I see, I was banging my head against the wall all day cause of this. Thanks so much for your input!

Answer (score 13):

Here is a similar solution as the one from @dev_junwen using a functional component and hooks. Also no need for a timeout.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from 'react';

const FirstInput = ({ item, save }) => {
    const innerRef = useRef();
    useEffect(() => innerRef.current && innerRef.current.focus());

    return <input ref={innerRef} />;
};
```

Comment: When using typescript, declare innerRef as: 
const innerRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>()

Answer (score 8):

Apparently there is a bug with react-bootstrap that doesn't allow `autoFocus` on a Modal component. The workaround while this bug is fixed is disabling animations on the Modal component.

```
    <Modal animation={false}>
      <Form.Control autoFocus />
    </Modal>
```

Comment: stopped working in 0.33.x

Answer (score 3):

Just add autoFocus = {false} on modal and autoFocus = {true} on input.

```
<Modal autoFocus={false}>
  <Form>
    <ModalHeader>Type Your Input</ModalHeader>
    <ModalBody>
      <Input autoFocus={true} />
      <Button>Submit</Button>
    </ModalBody>
  </Form>
</Modal>
```

Ref: https://simplernerd.com/js-reactstrap-modal-autofocus/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the onShow callback (that will be called after the animation is over) to set the focus to the inner field.

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';
    
const MyForm = () => {
    const innerRef = useRef();

    return (
       <Modal onShow={() => {innerRef.current.focus()}}>
           <Form.Control ref={innerRef} />
       </Modal>
   )
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is supplement to ALoR answer:
bootstrap docs suggest using `onEntered` callback which is fired after the Modal finishes transitioning in. It worked for me well.

Also suggested here "autoFocus = {false} on modal" is discouraged  as it messes up with screen readers

Answer (score 0):

I' got the solution without setTimeOut callback

```
 const inputRefs = useRef<HTMLInputElement[]>([]);

 const [check, setcheck] = useState(false);
 const activationCodeArray = ["","","","","",""]
 const [focusedElement,setfocusElelement] = useState(0) // update to onchange 



  useEffect(() => {
    if (isOpen) {
      if (inputRefs.current && check) {
        if (activationCodeArray[focusedElement] !== "" && focusedElement < 5) {
          inputRefs.current[focusedElement + 1].focus();
        } else {
          inputRefs.current[focusedElement].focus();
        }
      }
    }
    if (!isOpen) {
      setcheck(false);
    }
  }, [isOpen, check]);




 {activationCodeArray.map((str, index) => (
              <input
                maxLength={1}
                key={index}
                type="text"
                value={str}
                name={index.toString()}
                onChange={(event) => onChange(event, index)}
                ref={(input) => {
                  inputRefs.current[index] = input;
                  setcheck(true); // is true when rendered all input
                }}
              />
            ))}
```

on useEffect assign focus only if chek property is true

Answer (score -1):

It looks like you are using a string and not a bool when setting `autoFocus="false"` - should be `autoFocus={false}`. This is why it works the second time as you are setting the value correctly via the ref:  `this.inputRef.current.focus();`