# React: AutoFocus on Input field inside Modal

Tags: javascript, reactjs, modal-dialog, autofocus

I use Antd. I have Modal Window which consist Form. I want to focus in Input Field when user open the modal widnow. How i can do it in functional component? I try this but in not work for me:

```
const EditForm = ({visible, widget, onSave, onCancel}) => {
  const nameInput = useRef();
  useEffect(() => nameInput.current && nameInput.current.focus());
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
   return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        visible={visible}
        title='Edit'
        okText='Save'
        cancelText='Cancel'
        onCancel={onCancel}
        onOk={() => {
          form
            .validateFields()
            .then(values => {
              form.resetFields();
              onSave(values);
            })
            .catch(info => {
              console.log('Validate Failed:', info);
            });
        }}
      >
        <Form
          {...formItemLayout}
          layout={formLayout}
          form={form}
        >
          <Form.Item />
          <Form.Item
            name='nameWidget'
            label='Name'
          >
            <Input name='nameWidget' ref={nameInput} onChange={handleChangeName} placeholder='Введите новое название' />
          </Form.Item>

        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Comment: You can refer this answer for your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71736082/14219692

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this way.
good luck ;)

```
import React, {useState, useRef, useEffect}  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Modal, Button, Input, Form } from 'antd';


const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = useState(false)
  const myRef = useRef();

  /*
   *  This is the main different
   */
  useEffect(()=>{
    if (myRef && myRef.current) {
      const { input } = myRef.current
      input.focus()
    }

  })
  const showModal = () => {
    setVisible(true)
  };

  const handleOk = e => {
    setVisible(false)
  };

  const handleCancel = e => {
    setVisible(false)
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Button type="primary" onClick={showModal}>
        Open Modal with customized button props
      </Button>
      <Modal
        title="Basic Modal"
        visible={visible}
        onOk={handleOk}
        onCancel={handleCancel}
        okButtonProps={{ disabled: true }}
        cancelButtonProps={{ disabled: true }}
      >
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <p>Some contents...</p>
        <Form>
          <Form.Item>
            <Input ref={myRef} />
          </Form.Item>
        </Form>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('container'));
```

Comment: thank you, but i dont know how, but my code began work :D

Comment: Actually it works only once. I think that's because antd modal is not unmounted therefore the ref remain the same after one use

Answer (score 1):

You can actually accomplish this without using any refs at all.

First, put the `autoFocus` prop on your `Input`.

```
<Input autoFocus name='nameWidget' ref={nameInput} onChange={handleChangeName} placeholder='Введите новое название' />
```

This alone will not work yet as Ant Design renders modal dialogs outside of your application's root DOM element which trips up React's handling of `autoFocus`. If the root element is

```
<div id="app"></div>
```

as is customary, you need to tell Ant to render the Modal into this element by using the `getContainer` prop:

```
<Modal
  getContainer={document.getElementById('app')}
  // ...
>
```